# How can I remove name value pair object from json array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I'm trying to remove name/value objects from a JSON array. I have working code that is adding elements to another array. I just can't seem to remove elements from the original array that was added to the second array. The code that is adding elements does work. Thanks.

Sample json array:

```js
[
   {
      "key":"Company",
      "text":"Company"
   },
   {
      "key":"FirstName",
      "text":"First Name"
   },
   {
      "key":"Lastname",
      "text":"Last Name"
   },
   {
      "key":"StreetAddress",
      "text":"Street Address"
   },
   {
      "key":"City",
      "text":"City"
   },
   {
      "key":"State",
      "text":"State"
   },
   {
      "key":"zip",
      "text":"Zip"
   }
]
```

This is wrapped in a Vuejs function:

- `selected` is the original array and
- `selectedColumns` is the array I'm pushing to.

```js
oneToRight: function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.selected.forEach((el, i) => {
    this.selectedColumns.push({
      "key": el.key,
      "text": el.text
    });
    var del = this.selected.indexOf(this.selected);
    this.selected.splice(del, 1);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit Philipp. Appreciate it.

Comment: It's not clear what you want the result of this to be. Please show some examples of the data for `this.selected` and `this.selectedColumns` **before** this function runs and how you want them to look **after** it does

Comment: For example: If I have two arrays, array1 and array2. I push and element or elements from array1 to array2 I don't want the elements I pushed to exist in array1 anymore. I've done something similar with regular arrays but I have two JSON arrays with name/value objects as elements. I hope this adds some clarity. Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64147293/edit) to include the information I asked for. Don't provide vague statements either, show actual data examples for both **before** and **after** states

Comment: Oh, also the first part of the code works, pushing to the other array. I just can't seem to remove from the original array of the elements I pushed. Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just clear `selected` after you've finished copying?

Comment: remove `var del = this.selected.indexOf(this.selected);` and replace `del` in the next line with `I` - you already have the index of the original array in the variable `I`;

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to move all the items from `selected` to `selectedColumns`. You don't really need to splice it from `selected`. Just clear it with `this.selected = []` *after* you've copied the values:

```js
this.selectedColumns.push(...this.selected)
this.selected = []
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/KKzjwVe?editors=1010)

Comment: Thank you and for the code sample as well. Taking a look. Actually I also want to do a copy all but also if user selects I would like to remove from original array so it's not available to select again. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

From your vague comments, it sounds like you want the user to be able to pick individual elements from one array and move them into another.

To do so, you'd need to *splice* the item from the first array and *push* it to the other.

For example

```js
const options = [{"key":"Company","text":"Company"},{"key":"FirstName","text":"First Name"},{"key":"Lastname","text":"Last Name"},{"key":"StreetAddress","text":"Street Address"},{"key":"City","text":"City"},{"key":"State","text":"State"},{"key":"zip","text":"Zip"}]

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    options: [...options],
    selected: []
  }),
  methods: {
    select (index) {
      // remove and push
      this.selected.push(...this.options.splice(index, 1))
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app { display: flex; }
#app > div { flex: 1; }
.option { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <p>Available</p>
    <ul>
      <li
        class="option" 
        v-for="(option, index) in options" 
        :key="option.key" 
        @click="select(index)"
      >
        {{ option.text }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Selected</p>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="option in selected">
        {{ option.text }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh I see. Giving it a try. Thank you and greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Awesome! Worked great! I appreciate your help. I'll try to be more clear next time explaining the outcome. Thanks again.